# Show that a function is uniformly continuous. Where to start?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show that the following function is uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> {x  \sin \frac{1} {x}}, & \text{ }  x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1) \\
> 0, & \text{ }x  =  0.
> \end{cases} $$

We cannot use the theorem that a continuous function on a compact set K is continuous on K, because we don't have a compact set. I was told the following hint: *"if a function is uniformly continuous on a set then it is also uniformly continuous on any subset of this set"*. I don't know exactly what to do with this information, can you help me ? :)

I know the definition of uniform continuity, I (should) know what open, closed, compact sets are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that you can extend the definition to $[-1,1]$ and that it is continuous on the closed interval. Then use the theorem about uniform continuity.

Comment: Very fast way to have the conclusion (+1). Good to know that $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ fails to be U.C. in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: So you suggest that I define f(1)= sin(1) and f(-1)= - sin(-1), then show that the function is continious. Continious functions on a compact set are uniformly continious, and then use the hint, namely a (-1,1) is a subset of [-1,1] ?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with that. The "magic" happens at $x=0$ anyway.

Comment: @Hempo: Yes, exactly.